# API text doesnt register bold and space

Tags: javascript, html, api

Hello this is my first time I worked with API's I used coinmarketcap's API https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

This is my javascript code:

```
    $.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/", function(data) {      
    $("#altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap").html (100 - data.bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap.toFixed() + "%");   
    $("#total_market_cap_usd").html("$" + data.total_market_cap_usd.toLocaleString()); 
    });    

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        },
    });
});
```

This is my html

```
<div class="alt-coins-info">
    <p>
            <i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i>
            Added Altcoins: <b>10</b> / 
            <!-- "altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" not bold. no space between % en / -->
            Total Altcoin Marktcap: <b><div id="altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" > </div></b> / 
            <!-- no space between % en / -->
            Total Altcoin Dominance: <b><div id="total_market_cap_usd" > </div></b>
    </p>
</div>
```

There is a problem  "altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" is not bold and there no space between % and / , even tho I gave it the tag.

Thanks for reading I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using *Block-level* element (`div`), use `span` instead to render your data.

```js
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/", function(data) {
  $("#altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap").html((100 - data.bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap.toFixed()) + "%");
  $("#total_market_cap_usd").html("$" + data.total_market_cap_usd.toLocaleString());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: 'source',
    select: function(event, ui) {
      window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="alt-coins-info">
    <p>
            <i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i>
            Added Altcoins: <b>10</b> / 
            <!-- "altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" not bold. no space between % en / -->
            Total Altcoin Marktcap: <b><span id="altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" > </span></b> / 
            <!-- no space between % en / -->
            Total Altcoin Dominance: <b><span id="total_market_cap_usd" > </span></b>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`b`, `span`, etc. are inline containers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

`div` is a block container. 
Replace `<div id="altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" >` with `<span id="altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" >`:

```html
<div class="alt-coins-info">
    <p>
            <i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i>
            Added Altcoins: <b>10</b> / 
            <!-- "altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" not bold. no space between % en / -->
            Total Altcoin Marktcap: <b><span id="altcoin_percentage_of_market_cap" > </span></b> / 
            <!-- no space between % en / -->
            Total Altcoin Dominance: <b><span id="total_market_cap_usd" > </span></b>
    </p>
</div>
```